# Find the number of pairs of natural numbers from l to r which Bitwise AND is equal to 0

Tags: algorithm, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and

Given l and r, find the number of pairs of natural numbers from l to r which Bitwise AND is equal to 0.

Limits :

1 <= l <= r <= 10^9

r - l <= 10^6

I could only write a brute force. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this task? The range size is upto 10^6, so we could use that somehow.

Comment: Well, for each `n` in that range, you know which bits of the other numbers have to be `0` (all the bits that are `1` in that number). It should be possible (too lazy/busy to work out the details...) to calculate the number of numbers that have that property in that range. Then just sum them all up and divide by 2?

Comment: Yeah, I thought of doing a similar thing a couple minutes ago, but I have trouble working out the details. Thanks for responding though!!

Comment: For most inputs in your range the answer will be zero because r and r-10^6 will have the same max set bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First write the following function:

```
def and_i_lt_k  (i, k):
    ## Will return the number of numbers in the range 0..k
    ## whose and with i is 0
    ...
```

You can write that with your point about the bits - you just find the biggest nonzero bits that can work staying in range, remove the bits that MUST be 0, and you have the base 2 representation of one less than the number of ands that meet the condition. (The counting trick missed `0`.)

And now we use the following fact. Suppose that `x & y == 0`. Then:

1. `(2*x)     & (2*y)     == 0`
2. `(2*x + 1) & (2*y)     == 0`
3. `(2*x)     & (2*y + 1) == 0`

But `(2*x + 1) & (2*y + 1) == 1`.

So we can pair up most of the range from `l` to `r`, drop the bottom bit from `l` and `r` to get a smaller range, count the ands of the range, and then multiply by 3. We also have to be careful with the boundaries. So we get something like this:

```
def pairs_and_0 (l, r):
    # Base case
    if l == r:
      if l == 0:
          return 1
      else:
          return 0

    # Recursion.
    edge_pairs = 0
    # Edge case for the l-1 trick we will use.
    if 0 == l:
        edge_pairs += r
        l += 1

    # Is the top the first in an incomplete pair?
    if 0 == r%2:
        edge_pairs += and_i_lt_k(r, r) - and_i_lt_k(r, l-1)
        r -= 1

    # Is the bottom the second in an incomplete pair?
    if 1 == l%2:
        edge_pairs += and_i_lt_k(l, r) - and_i_lt_k(l, l-1)
        l += 1

    return edge_pairs + 3 * pairs_and_0(l//2, r//2)
```

This will be only 20 recursive calls to a trivial range. So it should be quite fast.